# Trying to sum numbers , but loop doesn't stop

Tags: assembly, average

Given the following code in Assembly:

```
.section .rodata

input_format:  .string  "%d"
output_format: .string  "%d\n"

    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main,@function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp,%ebp

    movl    $0,%ebx     # reset the sum register
    movl    $0,%esi     # reset the counter of the numbers
    movl    $0,%eax     # in order to know when to stop the loop
.loop:
    addl    $-8,%esp    # moving down the stack
    pushl   %esp
    pushl   $input_format
    call    scanf       # call scanf to get number from the user
    addl    $8,%esp
    addl    (%esp),%ebx # add the number to the total summary
    movl    (%esp),%ecx
    addl    $1,%esi     # add 1 to the counter
    pushl   $output_format
    call    printf      # print the given number
    cmpl    %ecx,%eax
    jne .loop

    # return from printf:
    movl    $0,%eax
    movl    %ebp,%esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

I'm trying to sum numbers larger than 0 in `ebx` and eventually calculate their average, but from some reason the loop wouldn't stop when I put a "0" (0 is suppose to be the end of the loop) .
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop terminates on comparison of ecx and eax.  eax is set to 0, but ecx doesn't appear to hold a count down value.  Also, are you sure that your functions are preserving your register values correctly?

Um, I bet that all your functions are modifying eax when they return - this is where return values are stored.  Move your eax assignment of 0 (or '0' / $30) down to just before the compare.  No need to set it until its needed anyways.

Comment: Regarding your question if the functions are preserving your register values correctly , I can't know since I haven't found yet a debugger that works well with assembly . Regarding eax and ecx , you think there's a problem with ecx ? I just want to store the given value by the user into ecx , no countdown . Just to stop the loop when the has entered "0" . thanks :)

Comment: Visual Studio does a fine job with assembler.  And so your scanf function is returning a characer code for what was entered?  If so, then you are getting ascii '0', not 0.  Try setting your eax value to '0' ($30 I believe) and using that.  That wasy both will compare against '0'.

Comment: Problem is ,that I need to use a gcc compiler.Does Visual Studio has a gcc compiler ?

Comment: Yes and no.  Yes you can compile gcc within visual studio, but no you wouldn't be able to use its debugger.  GDB seems to be the debugger of choice for gcc stuff, though I am far from an expert here.  Does changing your eax value fix your problem?

Comment: Okay,I'm done.I've tried to manipulate Eclipse to work with assembly and have succeeded.Debugger works great,the problem was that after each iteration (of a while loop) the registers doesn't "remember" their value .I think that I must use the stack in order to save values and never trust registers. Thanks !!!